# Yeoman yo conmand

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to use yeoman. 
I have not found anyone who has had this particular error. 
So far I have successfully installed Yeoman. When I run the `yo` command I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-sync.js:45
        throw err;
        ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/usr/sbin/authserver'
at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:875:3)
at exports.readdir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/fs.js:18:20)
at Object.safeCall [as safe] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/call.js:24:8)
at DirectoryReader.readNextDirectory (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:78:10)
at Readable.DirectoryReader.stream._read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:57:18)
at Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:455:10)
at readdirSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/index.js:27:21)
at Function.readdirSyncStat (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/index.js:34:10)
at ReaderSync.dynamicApi (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-sync.js:61:24)
at ReaderSync.api (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/fast-glob/out/providers/reader-sync.js:53:25)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at DirectoryReader.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:365:14)
at call.safe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/directory-reader.js:81:14)
at onceWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/call.js:45:17)
at onceWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/call.js:45:17)
at exports.readdir (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/fs.js:22:5)
at Object.safeCall [as safe] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/call.js:24:8)
[... lines matching original stack trace ...]
at readdirSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/@mrmlnc/readdir-enhanced/lib/sync/index.js:27:21)
```

Comment: So far I have moved past this error but now have another. I installed NVM and used that to install the latest `npm`. I reinstalled yeoman and generator-webapp, this time successfully without needing to enter `sudo`.  
The new error is: let index = _.findIndex(this.opt.choices.realChoices, ({ value }) => value === def);
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: Ny version of Node was old. 5.6.0 so I used nvm to install the latest version of Node. Now on 10.1.0. Now Yeoman works just fine.